# Codeigniter ajax get data from mysql and display in html form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have a list of names that I display and when a user clicks on edit, it opens a dialog with a html form. That form will then show the values of the data retrieved from the mysql table. However I am very confused as to how I can achieve that. This is what I have so far.

View

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th>Organisation</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Privilege Level</th>
    <th>Date Added</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php $offset = $this->uri->segment(4,0)+1; ?>
<?php foreach($user as $row): ?>
<tr data-id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
<td><?php echo $offset++; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->company; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->lastname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->privilege; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->date_added; ?></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input   type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input type="hidden"   name="set" value="edit"/><input type="button" class="editlink" value="Edit"/></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input  type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input type="hidden"  name="set" value="delete"/><input type="button" class="deletelink"  value="Delete"/></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php echo $links; ?>
</div>

<div id="edit-dialog">
<?php echo form_open('manager/users/edit_user'); ?>
<p>First Name : <input type="text" name="firstname"/></p>
<p>Last Name : <input type="text" name="lastname"/></p>
<p>NRIC : <input type="text" name="nric"/></p>
<p>Address : <input type="text" name="address"/></p>
<p>Username : <input type="text" name="username"/></p>
</form>
</div>
```

My controller

```
function get_user()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->load->model('user');
    $data = $this->user->retrieve($id);
}
```

My model

```
public function generate($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get($this->tablename);
    if($query->num_rows()==1)
    {
        return $query->result();    
    }
    else
    {
        return $query->result();    
    }
}
```

My Jquery/AJAX

```
$('.editlink').on('click', function() {
var user_id = $(this).parent().parent('tr').attr('data-id');
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/manager/users/get_user',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'text',
    data:{'id':user_id},
    cache:false,
    success:function(result){
            $("#edit-dialog").show();
            console.log($.parseJSON(result));
            $("#edit-dialog").dialog({
                    title: 'Edit User',
                    width: 400,
                    height: 500,
                    draggable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    dialogClass: "edit-user",
                    open: function(){

                    },
                    buttons: [
                                {
                                    text: 'Update',
                                    click: function() {
                                        $('#manipulate_user').submit();
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'Cancel',
                                    click: function() {
                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                                    }
                                }
                            ] 
            }); 
 }});

});
});
```

Comment: Im thinking if its better to preload everything and hide it first

Comment: In controller, you have `retrieve($id)` but you show `generate($id)` method of model.

Comment: Oops sorry. I must have renamed it. But the question remains. Is there a way to do it via Ajax or is it better to load everything into sub tables and hide them first

Comment: You have to echo json encode formatted string of result array from your controller back to AJAX function.